# To add a link on field value to navigate to Detail page for a Custom object in Reports

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-link

Hi  I'm new to salesforce reporting. I need your help.  I have a custom object called "Invoice". I have generated report for it.   Values present in the row should be displayed as hyperlinks, when i click on it, it should navigate to the Detail page of the custom object.

I have attached a screen capture for reference.

[image]

Comment: AjaySFDC - you ned to provide some more information - Is there a lookup field between Invoice__c and Sales Order? Same question for Invoice__c to Document__c  The hyperlinks won't appear unless the filed shown in the report is traversed through a lookup field

Comment: No there is no lookup field for that ! Can this be achieved ??

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, if there is no lookup field between Invoice__c and Sales_Order__c then I have to assume that the value of column `Sales Order Number` is coming from a text field within Invoice__c.

For argument's sake, let's assume that you can't re-engineer the schema to provide that lookup relationship (although this is the best answer).  So, what could you do?

**Option 1**

If there is a program (e.g. VF controller or some API client) that is inserting Sales Order Number into Invoice__c, modify that program to also insert a new field on Invoice called Sales_order_id__c with value of the ID of the Sales Order

**Option 2**

If there is a trigger on Invoice__c that can act on an insert or update event, modify that trigger to fetch the Sales Order id and place the value into a new field on Invoice__c called Sales_Order_Id__c

Then, under either option, create a formula field of type Hyperlink on Invoice that constructs a hyperlink whose value is `"\" & sales_order_id__c`. This formula field can be used on the report in lieu of the Sales Order Number text field

Repeat all of the above for the Document Number field

*Note that if the underlying Sales Order or Document is deleted, the text field reference to that custom object is broken and the hyperlink will also be broken*

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go to detail page of Invoice on click of Sales order number.

- Make a new formula field on custom object as Sales order number and add below formula

  HYPERLINK("/" &Id, sales_order_number__c);

Now add this field in report and you will be able redirect back to your detail page of custom object Invoice.